# Mac OS X Terminal is not sourcing the resource file until the Terminal is closed and restarted?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

Can somebody explain how the terminal is sourced in Mac OS X please. I have been having to turn it off and on all day for changes to take effect when editing shell files.

Yes this is also a problem with VIM sourcing, though this seems to be unresolvable at the minute? I have [another thread about this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/970168/vim-resource-file-not-being-sourced-when-saving-a-file-nor-sourcing-manually).

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I think perhaps you're editing your .bashrc profile or other such "init" files?  These are sourced when the shell starts. There are some that are sourced at login, some that are sourced when X starts, etc, but I'm guessing your talking about shell init files.  If you want to load those changes without closing terminal, you can just start a new shell, or you can also just re-read the file into the existing shell (syntax differs for each shell).

Comment: yes i am using bash_profile. could you expand on re-reading the file into the existing shell? I'm using xterm on a mac.

Comment: Just type `source ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using bash as your shell, check out the snippet below from [this page](http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#shellStartup).

> **Bash Startup Files**
>
> When a "login shell" starts up, it reads the file
>   `/etc/profile` and then `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` or
>   `~/.profile` (whichever one exists - it only reads one of these,
>   checking for them in the order mentioned).
>
> When a "non-login shell" starts up, it reads the file `/etc/bashrc`
>   and then the file `~/.bashrc`.
>
> Note that when bash is invoked with the name "sh", it tries to mimic
>   the startup sequence of the Bourne shell ("sh"). In particular, a
>   non-login shell invoked as "sh" does not read any dot files by
>   default. See the [bash man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) for details.

Comment: Agreed that sourcing the file addresses the symptom but the OP asked to "explain how the terminal is sourced in Mac OS X".